# Convert Bitcoin private key from file text

Tags: python, bitcoin, private-key

Good afternoon, friends, I just started learning python, I found this code that suits my needs, but on the way out everything is synchronized in one line, help me with this problem.
"

```
import ecdsa
import hashlib
import base58


with open("my_private_key.txt", "r") as f:    #Input file path
  for line in f:

              #Convert hex private key to bytes
     private_key = bytes.fromhex(line)      

              #Derivation of the private key
     signing_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
     verifying_key = signing_key.get_verifying_key()

     public_key = bytes.fromhex("04") + verifying_key.to_string()

             #Hashes of public key
     sha256_1 = hashlib.sha256(public_key)
     ripemd160 = hashlib.new("ripemd160")
     ripemd160.update(sha256_1.digest())

             #Adding prefix to identify Network
     hashed_public_key = bytes.fromhex("00") + ripemd160.digest()

             #Checksum calculation
     checksum_full = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(hashed_public_key).digest()).digest()
     checksum = checksum_full[:4]

             #Adding checksum to hashpubkey         
     bin_addr = hashed_public_key + checksum

             #Encoding to address
     address = str(base58.b58encode(bin_addr))
     final_address = address[2:-1]

     print(final_address)

     with open("my_addresses.txt", "a") as i:
        i.write(final_address)
```

"

Comment: Hello and welcome @kamburishka, in order for people to properly respond to your question, I think it would be helpful if you could elaborate. When you say "everything is synchronized in one line," are you saying that it's difficult to read/interpret the output because it's presented in one large chunk?

Answer (score 0):

`print` writes a trailing newline after writing all its arguments. `write` does not; you have to supply it yourself.

```
with open("my_addresses.txt", "a") as i:
    i.write(final_address + "\n")
```

Or, you can use `print`:

```
with open("my_addresses.txt", "a") as i:
    print(final_address, file=i)
```

Ignoring many of its keyword arguments, `print` is defined something like

```
def print(*args, end='\n', sep=' ', file=sys.stdout):
    file.write(sep.join(args))
    file.write(end)
```

Also, note that you don't need to repeatedly open your output file. You can open it at the same time as the input and leave it open for the duration of the loop.

```
with open("my_private_key.txt", "r") as f, \
     open("my_addresses.txt", "a") as i:
    for line in f:
        ...
        print(final_address, file=i)
```

Comment: Dear friend @chepner, you can't tell me how to add multithreading to this script, it works very slowly